# Выбор фреймворка для CRM

Tags: node.js, backend, crm

Мы в компании разрабатываем внутреннюю CRM систему. И вместо того, чтобы писать свой back-end владелец хочет использовать готовые варианты и строить свою экосистему уже вокруг них. Вопрос: Какие есть варианты? От чего отталкиваться? Или может еще какие-то идеи можете подкинуть, буду весьма благодарен.

Answer (score 2):

Возьмите [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/). Это обертка поверх Express, которая очень напоминает Spring, ASP.Net Core и другие enterprise фреймворки.

```
import { Get, Controller } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  render() {
    const message = this.appService.getHello();
    return { message };
  }
}
```

К нему сразу подключайте [TypeORM](https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm), для каждой модели реализуйте [паттерн Репозиторий](https://medium.com/@phatdev/how-to-build-a-scalable-maintainable-application-with-nestjs-mongodb-apply-the-design-patterns-7b287af61354). Для чтения списков элементов с сортировками, фильтрами и пагинацией используйте модуль [nest-paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-paginate)

```
import { Controller, Injectable, Get } from '@nestjs/common'
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm'
import { FilterOperator, Paginate, PaginateQuery, paginate, Paginated } from 'nestjs-paginate'
import { Repository, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from 'typeorm'

@Entity()
export class CatEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column('text')
  name: string

  @Column('text')
  color: string

  @Column('int')
  age: number
}

@Injectable()
export class CatsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(CatEntity)
    private readonly catsRepository: Repository<CatEntity>
  ) {}

  public findAll(query: PaginateQuery): Promise<Paginated<CatEntity>> {
    return paginate(query, this.catsRepository, {
      sortableColumns: ['id', 'name', 'color', 'age'],
      searchableColumns: ['name', 'color', 'age'],
      defaultSortBy: [['id', 'DESC']],
      filterableColumns: {
        age: [FilterOperator.GTE, FilterOperator.LTE],
      },
    })
  }
}

@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {
  constructor(private readonly catsService: CatsService) {}

  @Get()
  public findAll(@Paginate() query: PaginateQuery): Promise<Paginated<CatEntity>> {
    return this.catsService.findAll(query)
  }
}
```

Модуль позволит выводить списки элементов в формате [json-api](https://jsonapi.org/format/) используя запросы следующего вида

```
http://localhost:3000/cats?limit=5&page=2&sortBy=color:DESC&search=i&filter.age=$gte:3
```

На фронт возьмите React, TypeScript, [Mobx](https://mobx.js.org/README.html), [InversifyJS](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS). Позволит писать состояние приложения на ООП с инъекцией зависимостей.

[image: react-declarative]

Для реализации списочных форм и форм элемента списка можно воспользоваться [этим Storybook](https://github.com/react-declarative/react-declarative-storybook) с набором готовых компонентов, осуществляющих генерацию верстки на основе JSON шаблона